# No icons on buttons on GTK# apps

Tags: release-loki, gtk

I stack with the problem with mono app written on GTK#. I try to change org.gnome.desktop.interface buttons-have-icons to true which solve this problem in Freya, but it didn't solve problem in Loki. Is there are any other ways to solve this problem?